# Formulário HTML e PHP

Tags: php, html5

Como funciona para mandar para o e-mail ou de acordo com o plano de hospedagem poder acessar os formulários dos clientes do site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Atila Silva</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">



    <header>
    <nav id="i">

    </nav>

    <nav id="menu">
        <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
            <ul type="disc">
            <li > <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li> <a href="contatos.html"> Contatos</a></li>
            <li> <a href="img.html">Imagens</a> </li>
            <li><a href="fale-conosco.html">Fale Conosco</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="interface">
    <form method="get" action="form.php">

        <fieldset id="usuario">
        <legend id="usuario">Identificação do Usuário</legend>
        <p> <label for="cnome">Nome:</label> <input type="text" name="nome" id="cnome" size="20" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nome Completo"> </p>
        <p><label for="cemail">Email:</label> <input type="Email" name="email" id="cemail" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="digite seu email"> </p>
        <fieldset id="sexo"><legend id="sexo"> Sexo:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="cmasc" value="Homem" > <label for="cmasc" id="masc" >Masculino</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="cfem" value="Mulher" /> <label for="cfem" id="fem" > Feminino </label></fieldset>
        <p><label for="cnasc">Data de Nascimento </label><input type="date" name="tnasc" id="cnasc"> </p>
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="endereco">
    <legend id="endereco">Endereço do Usuário</legend>
        <p><label for="crua">Logradouro:</label> <input type="text" name="rua" id="crua" size="13" maxlength="80" placeholder="RUA,AV,TRAV,etc"></p>
        <p><label for="cnum">Número:</label> <input type="number" name="num" id="cnum" min="0" max="99999"></p>
        <p><label for="cest">Estado:</label><select name="test" id="est">
            <option value="0">Selecione o Estado</option>
            <option value="ac">Acre</option>
            <option value="al">Alagoas</option>
            <option value="ap">Amapá</option>
            <option value="am">Amazonas</option>
            <option value="ba">Bahia</option>
            <option value="ce">Ceará</option>
            <option value="df">Distrito Federal</option>
            <option value="es">Espirito Santo</option>
            <option value="go">Goiás</option>
            <option value="ma">Maranhão</option>
            <option value="ms">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
            <option value="mt">Mato Grosso</option>
            <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option>
            <option value="pa">Pará</option>
            <option value="pb">Paraíba</option>
            <option value="pr">Paraná</option>
            <option value="pe">Pernambuco</option>
            <option value="pi">Piauí</option>
            <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option>
            <option value="rn">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
            <option value="rs">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
            <option value="ro">Rondônia</option>
            <option value="rr">Roraima</option>
            <option value="sc">Santa Catarina</option>
            <option selected="São Paulo" value="sp">São Paulo</option>
            <option value="se">Sergipe</option>
            <option value="to">Tocantins</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><label for="ccity">Cidade:</label><input type="text" name="city" id="ccity" size="20" maxlength="40" placeholder="Nome da Cidade"></p>
    </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="mensagem">
        <legend id="msg">Mensagem do Usuário</legend>
            <p><label>Grau de Urgência:</label>Mín<input type="range" name="urg" id="curg" min="0" max="10" step="5">Máx</p>
            <p><label for="cmsg">Mensagem:</label>
                <textarea name="msg" id="cmsg" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Deixe aqui sua mensagem"></textarea></p>
            </fieldset>


            <input type="submit" name="Enviar" >
            <input type="reset" name="Limpar">

        </form>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>php</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>FORMULÁRIO</h1>
    <?php

    $vnome= isset($_GET["nome"])?$_GET["nome"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vemail= isset($_GET["email"])?$_GET["email"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vsexo= isset($_GET["sexo"])?$_GET["sexo"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vnasc= isset($_GET["tnasc"])?$_GET["tnasc"]:"[Não informado]";
    $vrua= isset($_GET["rua"])?$_GET["rua"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vnum= isset($_GET["num"])?$_GET["num"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vtest= isset($_GET["test"])?$_GET["test"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vcity= isset($_GET["city"])?$_GET["city"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vurg= isset($_GET["urg"])?$_GET["urg"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vmsg= isset($_GET["msg"])?$_GET["msg"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $idade=date("Y")-$vnasc;
    echo "Digitou <br/> $vnome <br/> $vemail <br/> $vsexo <br/> $idade <br/> $vrua <br/> $vnum <br/> $vtest <br/> $vcity <br/> $vurg <br/> $vmsg <br/>";




    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você quer enviar por email os dados ao submeter o formulario  ?

Comment: Não sei como funciona muito bem porque sou novo, mas se for possível enviar por e-mail é melhor pode me ensinar?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde  ,

Assumindo que você deseje enviar para o email os dados submetidos no formulario , você deve importar a biblioteca do phpmailer.

Identificação do Usuário

Nome:

Email:

Sexo:
             Masculino
              Feminino

Data de Nascimento

Endereço do Usuário

Logradouro:

Número:

Estado:
            Selecione o Estado
            Acre
            Alagoas
            [...]

Cidade:

Mensagem do Usuário

Grau de Urgência:MínMáx

Mensagem:

```
    <?php


            $vnome= isset($_POST["nome"])?$_POST["nome"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vemail= isset($_POST["email"])?$_POST["email"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vsexo= isset($_POST["sexo"])?$_POST["sexo"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vnasc= isset($_POST["tnasc"])?$_POST["tnasc"]:"[Não informado]";
    $vrua= isset($_POST["rua"])?$_POST["rua"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vnum= isset($_POST["num"])?$_POST["num"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vtest= isset($_POST["test"])?$_POST["test"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vcity= isset($_POST["city"])?$_POST["city"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vurg= isset($_POST["urg"])?$_POST["urg"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $vmsg= isset($_POST["msg"])?$_POST["msg"]:"[Não Informado]";
    $idade=date("Y")-$vnasc;

              $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
              $header .= "Content-type: : multipart/related; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 

             //Importamos o phpMailer
          require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

               //Nova instância do PHPMailer
                $mail = new PHPMailer;

                $mail->IsSMTP();   //Informa que será utilizado o SMTP para envio do e-mail
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                $mail->Port       = 587;
                $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";  //SMTP
                $mail->Username =  "seuemail@mail.com.br"; //EMAIL QUE IRA ENVIAR
                $mail->Password =   "senhadoseuemail";        //SENHA EMAIL

                //Assunto do e-mail que será enviado
                $mail->Subject  =   "TITULO DO EMAIL";

                //Preenchimento do campo FROM do e-mail
                $mail->From = "seuemail@mail.com.br";
                $mail->FromName = "SEU NOME";

                 //Dados do formulario
                $data = date('d/m/Y');
                //E-mail para a qual o e-mail será enviado
                $mail->AddAddress($email);

              // HTML COM O CORPO DO EMAIL

              $corpo = "";
              $mail->Body = $corpo;
              $mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;
              if($mail->Send()){
                  print "Email enviado com sucesso!!";
              }else{
                  print "Falha ao enviar o email!!";
}

            ?>
```

Comment: BOA TARDE!!Com esse código eu consigo, mesmo depois do site estar hospedado receber o formulário por e-mail?

Comment: Boa tarde, sim . Altere aqui *//E-mail para a qual o e-mail será enviado
                $mail->AddAddress($email);*  a variavel $email para o email que vc deseja que o sistema envia .

Comment: Ok vou fazer uns testes aqui. Obrigado !!!

Comment: Ok , qualquer coisa sinaliza aqui.

Answer (score 0):

O PHPMailer é uma classe pronta para envio das mensagens utilizando autenticação no servidor de e-mails de seu domínio muito utilizado por todo o mundo.

O PHPMailer 6 foi lançado no final de agosto de 2017, trazendo inúmeras novidades e melhorias em relação à versão 5.

A biblioteca PHPMailer pode ser baixada em seu site oficial [**GitHub - PHPMailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Descompacte e publique em uma pasta do servidor exemplo **`mailer`**.

Arquivo php, exemplo **`PHPMailerForm.php`**, publique na mesma pasta dos arquivos baixados e descompactados **`mailer`**.

**Exemplo - Estrutura:**

> Não é necessário publicar todos os arquivos e pastas descompactados, basta os indicados na figura abaixo

[image: diretorio]

**Arquivo PHP**

```
/******* CODIGO EMAIL *******/

//Essa condição você faz do jeito que achar melhor
if ((isset($_POST['$vemail']))&&(!empty($_POST['$vemail']))){

   //método POST
   $vnome= isset($_POST["nome"])?$_POST["nome"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vemail= isset($_POST["email"])?$_POST["email"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vsexo= isset($_POST["sexo"])?$_POST["sexo"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vnasc= isset($_POST["tnasc"])?$_POST["tnasc"]:"[Não informado]";
   $vrua= isset($_POST["rua"])?$_POST["rua"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vnum= isset($_POST["num"])?$_POST["num"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vtest= isset($_POST["test"])?$_POST["test"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vcity= isset($_POST["city"])?$_POST["city"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vurg= isset($_POST["urg"])?$_POST["urg"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $vmsg= isset($_POST["msg"])?$_POST["msg"]:"[Não Informado]";
   $idade=date("Y")-$vnasc;

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    // Inclui os arquivo localizados na pasta src
    require_once 'src/Exception.php';
    require_once 'src/PHPMailer.php';
    require_once 'src/SMTP.php';

    // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

    try {
        // Configurações do servidor
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.com';          // Endereço do servidor SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // autenticação SMTP
        $mail->Username = 'nome@domiio.com';     // Usuário do servidor SMTP
        $mail->Password = 'secreta';            // Senha da caixa postal utilizada
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';             // Ativar criptografia TLS, `ssl` também é aceita
        $mail->Port = 587;                    // TCP port to connect to

        // Define o remetente   
        $mail->setFrom($vemail, $vnome);    // email e nome do remetente


        // Define o(s) destinatário(s)
        $mail->addAddress('destinatario@dominio.com', 'Nome destinatario');

        // Destinatários abaixo são opcionais 
        //$mail->addAddress('fulano@dominio.com');                    // outro destinatario
        //$mail->addReplyTo($vemail, $vnome);                        //aqui você coloca o endereço de quem está enviando a mensagem pela sua página
        //$mail->addCC('cc@edominio.com');                          // Copia
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@dominio.com');                        // Copia oculta

        //Anexos
        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Adicionar um anexo
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');   // Nome opcional

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                 // true define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML, se false, desativa
        $mail->Subject = 'Digite a assunto aqui';           // Assunto da mensagem

        //Define o corpo do email
        $mail->Body = "Seus dados <br/> $vnome <br/> $vemail <br/> $vsexo <br/> $idade <br/> $vrua <br/> $vnum <br/> $vtest <br/> $vcity <br/> $vurg <br/> $vmsg <br/>";;

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    //caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Mensagem não pode ser enviada.';
        echo 'Erro do Mailer: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;   //Mensagem de erro do PHPMailer
    }

}
```

**HTML**

Use o método POST que utiliza a URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) para envio de informações ao servidor. A URI não é retornável ao cliente, o que torna o método POST mais seguro, pois não expõe os dados enviados no navegador.

```
 <!-- para enviar para a mesma pagina -->
 <form action="" method="post">

 <!-- se o seu script estiver em outra pagina -->
 <form action="URL_DO_SCRIPT" method="post">
 ...................
 ...................
/******* FIM CODIGO EMAIL *******/
```