# Formulário de contato

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Boa noite.

Galera, seguinte.

Estou começando há pouco tempo em HTML5, então ainda não manjo muito.

Eu fiz toda a parte visual (CSS) de um formulário de contato (como trabalho do curso), porém eu não sou muito bom com o html em si, então a minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Quais códigos eu devo utilizar para quando a pessoa clicar em "Enviar", a mensagem realmente ir para o e-mail? Pois fazendo testes, quando clico em "Enviar" não acontece nada, apenas redireciona para a index.

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar dados do formulário por e-mail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260108/enviar-dados-do-formul%c3%a1rio-por-e-mail)

Comment: Qual linguagem vc usa, PHP?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185238/enviar-email-somente-com-html/185240#185240 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/como-enviar-um-email-a-partir-de-um-formulario-de-um-site-em-html

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar um email a partir de um formulario de um site em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/como-enviar-um-email-a-partir-de-um-formulario-de-um-site-em-html)

Comment: você pode fazer isso com javascript e php e com um botão do tipo submit, lembre-se de deixar o seu formulário dentro da tag <form></form> , acredito que com apenas html não seja possível resolver seu problema, posso estar enganado. Voce pode inserir um ajax no seu codigo, mas precisa-ra criar um arquivo php

Comment: Para isso tu precisa utilizar uma linguagem de programação. *PHP*, por exemplo.
No caso do *PHP*, tu pode usar a função *mail* nativa nele ou a classe *PHPMailer*.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/como-enviar-e-mails-somente-com-o-b%c3%a1sico-de-html5)

Comment: Não entendi porque essa pergunta não foi marcada como duplicata mesmo depois de tantas sinalizações.